# HR:MIN:SEC to sec in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with time in the format of [hr:min:sec] such as 1:20:30. How can I convert it to seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula in an adjacent column, e.g. with 1:20:30 in A2 use this formula in B2

=A2*86400

[86400 is the number of seconds in a day]

format B2 as general and you get the result 4830

alternatively you could simply custom format A2 as

[s]

that should display as the same